# WPF add button in combobox

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, itemtemplate

I want to add button in combobox, which contains ItemTemplate. First, that I tried was this:

```
<ComboBox Name="oilWells_comboBox"
          Style="{StaticResource MMComboBox}"
          MaxWidth="100"
          ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.OilWellCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:MainWindow}}"
          Margin="0">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDisplay}" Checked="FilterDataGrid" Unchecked="FilterDataGrid">
                    <CheckBox.Content>
                        <TextBlock MinWidth="100" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                    </CheckBox.Content>
                </CheckBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <Button Content="Clear" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></Button>
</ComboBox>
```

But I've got an exception, which said what i cant add items to control, which has ItemTemplate. The second one was this:

```
<ComboBox Name="oilWells_comboBox"
          Style="{StaticResource MMComboBox}"
          MaxWidth="100"
          ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.OilWellCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:MainWindow}}"
          Margin="0">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDisplay}" Checked="FilterDataGrid" Unchecked="FilterDataGrid">
                    <CheckBox.Content>
                        <TextBlock MinWidth="100" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                        <Button Content="Clear" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></Button>
                    </CheckBox.Content>
                </CheckBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

But in this case button adds after each checkbox. Have you any ideas, how to do this only once? Thanks you in advance)

Comment: edit `Template` property of ComboBox itself. In VS right click on CB, select `Edit Template` - `Edit copy` and then add Button in that template

Comment: Your question isn't clear -
Do you want the button as one of the options in the ComboBox?
Do you want to create your own ComboBox which contains a button?
Do you want each option in the ComboBox to contain a button?

Comment: I want to add a button as the first combobox item, and the all next items must be items from ItemsTemplate

Answer (score 1):

1. Right Click ComboBox in designer surface / or in Document Outline at the left side outside designer surface > Edit Template > Edit copy.
2. This will generate some Styles under `Window.Resources`, find `ItemsPresenter` and wrap it with `StackPanel` and `Button` as shown below :

   ```
   <StackPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
      <Button Content="Additional"/>
      <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
   </StackPanel>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in windows loaded event and it should work.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Content = "My Button";
    b.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(MyBtn_Click);
    oilWells_comboBox.Items.Add(b);
}
```